# How to get the contact added date and time in Android

Tags: android

Am getting Contact's name, number, email, address.... but i cant able to get the contact added date and time...here my piece of code.. Any idea...
Thanks in advance

```
 private void getDetails() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA };
    Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);

    int indexName = names
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = names
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    names.moveToFirst();
    do {

        String name = names.getString(indexName);
        Log.e("Name new:", name);
        String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
        Log.e("Number new:", "::" + number);

    } while (names.moveToNext());
```

// Fore email

```
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor email = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { id }, null);
        while (email.moveToNext()) {
            // to get the contact names
            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
            String emailid = email
                    .getString(email
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            Log.e("Email id ::", emailid);
            String emailType = email
                    .getString(email
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
            Log.e("Email Type ::", emailType);

        }
        email.close();
    }
```

// For address

```
  while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Cursor addrCur = cr
                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
        while (addrCur.moveToNext()) {
            String street = addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
            Log.e("Street ::", street);
            String city = addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
            Log.e("City ::", city);
            String state = addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
            Log.e("State ::", state);
            String postalCode = addrCur
                    .getString(addrCur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
            Log.e("Postal Code ::", postalCode);
        }
        addrCur.close();

    }

}
```

Like above how do i get the date of inserted contact ??

Comment: LL50 : by adding "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP ", am getting null ....Actually i need date of respective inserted contacts. For ex : If i added contact yesterday (13.11.2013), i need this date...ok